# How to configure gmap in template file

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

I override node display for content type Match Fixtures by creating node--match-fixtures.tpl.php file and put code below:

```
<?php
$location = $content['field_stadium'][0]['#locations'];
$stadium_map = array('id' => 'stadium_map',
             'latitude' => $location['latitude'],
             'longitude'=> $location['longitude'],
             'zoom'     => 13,
             'width'    => '100%',
             'height'   => '400px',
             'type'     => 'Satellite',
);

echo theme('gmap', array('#settings' => $stadium_map)) 
?>
```

But it show wrong map and also not 100% width. I use gmap and location module. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If its showing the wrong map, you might be displaying the wrong view mode. Make sure you have set the gmap display for view mode full.